# Incrementing MySql variable by SUM() not correct

Tags: mysql

I am trying to put together a query that groups records by date along with a total for that particular date (there can be multiple entries in a day) but I also need a running total that I intended on using a MySQL variable for. My issue is that the cumulative total column seems to contain the SUM() for just that date.

So this works fine for the daily totals

```
SELECT
YEAR(log_at) as year,
MONTH(log_at) as month,
DAY(log_at) as day,
SUM(ev) as dailyTotal,
count(*) as count
FROM tracks
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month, day
ORDER BY year, month, day ASC
```

Add what I thought was going to be a fairly simple variable in there to keep track of the running total

```
SET @cumulative := 0;

SELECT
YEAR(log_at) as year,
MONTH(log_at) as month,
DAY(log_at) as day,
SUM(ev) as dailyTotal,
@cumulative := @cumulative + sum(ev) AS cumulative,
count(*) as count
FROM tracks
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month, day
ORDER BY year, month, day ASC
```

[image]
And the cumulative variable just contains the total for that day. But if I change it to increment by 1 instead of the SUM() it seems to work correctly

[image]

Any advice for achieving the desired behaviour is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is stored in the column `ev`?

Comment: Just a double value, nothing fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create the whole selection and only then do your cumulative-stuff because you can't append the sum of a column of your GROUP BY at the same time (I don't really know why dough)

```sql
SELECT 
`year`,
`month`,
`day`,
`dailyTotal`,
@cum := @cum + `dailyTotal` as `cumulative`,
`count`
FROM
(
SELECT
YEAR(log_at) as year,
MONTH(log_at) as month,
DAY(log_at) as day,
SUM(ev) as dailyTotal,
count(*) as count
FROM tracks
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month, day
ORDER BY year, month, day ASC
) a
JOIN (SELECT @cum := 0) b
```

I tested it with a bit less intensive tables... maybe I got this one wrong here. But I hope you get the theory.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Seems like a long winded work around but does the trick